# How can I add html tags using .innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tags, innerhtml

I have an element that I want to update the innerhtml text and icon but my  tag is being ignored.

```
 document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next
 <i class="icon icon--right icon-arrow-right"></i>";
}
```

Comment: Replace the outer double quotes of your HTML string with single quotes.

Comment: "Next <i class="icon icon--right icon-arrow-right"></i>" should probably be 'Next
 <i class="icon icon--right icon-arrow-right"></i>'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the inner double quotes `"` in your string, or change your outer quotes to single quotes `'`; Examples:

```
document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next <i class=\"icon icon--right icon-arrow-right\"></i>";

document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = 'Next <i class="icon icon--right icon-arrow-right"></i>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML string should be **formatted** with **single quotes instead of double quote**.

Current is:

```
 document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next
 <i class="icon icon--right icon-arrow-right"></i>";
```

Change to:

```
document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = 'Next<i class = "icon icon--right icon-arrow-right" ></i>';
```

Answer (score 1):

**You must put single quotes instead of double quote**

```
document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = 'Next<i class = "icon icon--right icon-arrow-right" ></i>';
```